# Is there away to... ahem... "flip convexity" in AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, anchor-point, path-effects

For example:
If I create a rounded rectangle and spend a few minutes adjusting the "roundness" of the corners, till I get it the way I want...
Is there a way to turn these corners from convex to concave, while preserving the roundness value?
In the end it wouldn't look like a rounded rectangle, but like a rectangle that someone with a perfect jaw has bitten off the corners of...

Comment: ..... VectorScribe.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer version(s), you can direct-select the path and then double click the Live Corners widget that should appear near the corner.

Without live corners you can try: (after you set the roundness) select the corner anchor points individually, and then rotate them. Upper left: 90, lower left, -90 etc

Comment: Live corners would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but you could make circles and "minus front" from Pathfinder.
[image]